# String to array of array

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax routine that return a string that looks something like this

```
[["analog.__VG_SPP3_SFRTPCT","analog.__VG_SPP3_SFRTPCT"],
 ["analog._3305_LIST210_1","analog._3305_LIST210_1"],
 ["analog._AG_5340_PR14AN","analog._AG_5340_PR14AN"],
 ["analog._AG_EPNT_2","analog._AG_EPNT_2"],
 ["analog._AG_EPNT_SP","analog._AG_EPNT_SP"],
 ["analog._AG_MERC_ERXTES","analog._AG_MERC_ERXTES"],
 ["analog._AG_ROC_TEST","analog._AG_ROC_TEST"],
 ["analog._AG_ROM1_LOAD","analog._AG_ROM1_LOAD"],
 ["analog._AG_TEST_CRC1LT","analog._AG_TEST_CRC1LT"],
 ["analog._AG_TEST_CRC1RT","analog._AG_TEST_CRC1RT"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_MDP1CV","analog._CWAV_TST_MDP1CV"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_MDP1CV_LIST","analog._CWAV_TST_MDP1CV_LIST"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_MDP2CV","analog._CWAV_TST_MDP2CV"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_MDP2CV_LIST","analog._CWAV_TST_MDP2CV_LIST"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_MOR1CV","analog._CWAV_TST_MOR1CV"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_MOR1CV_LIST","analog._CWAV_TST_MOR1CV_LIST"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_MOR2CV_LIST","analog._CWAV_TST_MOR2CV_LIST"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_TIME001","analog._CWAV_TST_TIME001"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_TIME002","analog._CWAV_TST_TIME002"],
 ["analog._CWAV_TST_TIME003","analog._CWAV_TST_TIME003"]]
```

What is the easiest and fastest way of converting that string into an array of arrays, the syntax is practically the same as if you were to define the same structure in javascript, is there a way to execute it as javascript and get an array variable out of it?

Comment: `var myArray = JSON.parse(arrayString);`

Answer (score 3):

This is called [**JSON**](http://json.org).

You're looking for `JSON.parse`.

Comment: not sure why it was voted down, it looks like a JSON response, and if you parse it as JSON you'd get a multidimensional array.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted; it is correct.

Comment: Absolutely right, I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use JSON (Javascript Object Notation).

Something like:

```
var analogObject = JSON.parse(analogString);
```

You can turn it back to a string then with:

```
var analogString = JSON.stringify(analogObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and parse the response text. This will give you your array of arrays.